# How to Perform Sum From Same Table Using Parent-Child Relation

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

I have a table where a family monthly expenditure is stored. In this table there have a parent-child relation. From here I want to get total amount of expenditure for the family. So how can I update `TOTAL_AMOUNT` column or do that thing?

For enquiry I give dummy table and insert script.

```
CREATE TABLE PARENT_CHILD
(
   ID             NUMBER (10),
   PARENT_ID      NUMBER (10),
   OWN_AMOUNT     NUMBER (20),
   TOTAL_AMOUNT   NUMBER (20)
);

INSERT INTO PARENT_CHILD VALUES (1, NULL, 100000, NULL);
INSERT INTO PARENT_CHILD VALUES (2, NULL, 15000, NULL);
INSERT INTO PARENT_CHILD VALUES (3, NULL, 10000, NULL);
INSERT INTO PARENT_CHILD VALUES (4, 3, 2000, NULL);
INSERT INTO PARENT_CHILD VALUES (5, NULL, 100000, NULL);
INSERT INTO PARENT_CHILD VALUES (6, 5, 25000, NULL);
INSERT INTO PARENT_CHILD VALUES (7, 6, 15000, NULL);
INSERT INTO PARENT_CHILD VALUES (8, 5, 30000, NULL);
INSERT INTO PARENT_CHILD VALUES (9, 5, 20000, NULL);
INSERT INTO PARENT_CHILD VALUES (10, 5, 8000, NULL);
INSERT INTO PARENT_CHILD VALUES (11, 10, 2000, NULL);
```

For example I want to update table like following:

| ID | PARENT_ID | OWN_AMOUNT | TOTAL_AMOUNT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 |  | 100000 | 100000 |
| 2 |  | 15000 | 15000 |
| 3 |  | 10000 | 12000 |
| 4 | 3 | 2000 | 2000 |
| 5 |  | 100000 | 200000 |
| 6 | 5 | 25000 | 40000 |
| 7 | 6 | 15000 | 15000 |
| 8 | 5 | 30000 | 30000 |
| 9 | 5 | 20000 | 20000 |
| 10 | 5 | 8000 | 10000 |
| 11 | 10 | 2000 | 2000 |

*Thanks in advance.*

Answer (score 1):

As there are more than parent-child (but also grandchild and - possibly - even deeper) relationship, you'll need a recursive CTE to correctly say *who is who* and update the source table.

Something like this:

```
SQL> update parent_child pc set
  2    pc.total_amount =
  3      (with
  4          children (parent, child) as
  5            (select parent_id, id
  6             from parent_child
  7             union all
  8             select d.parent, a.id
  9             from children d join parent_child a on d.child = a.parent_id
 10            )
 11        select
 12          sum(a.own_amount) amount
 13        from children c join parent_child a on a.id = c.child
 14        where nvl(c.parent, c.child) = pc.id
 15        group by nvl(c.parent, c.child)
 16       );

11 rows updated.
```

Result:

```
SQL> select * from parent_child order by id;

        ID  PARENT_ID OWN_AMOUNT TOTAL_AMOUNT
---------- ---------- ---------- ------------
         1                100000       100000
         2                 15000        15000
         3                 10000        12000
         4          3       2000         2000
         5                100000       200000
         6          5      25000        40000
         7          6      15000        15000
         8          5      30000        30000
         9          5      20000        20000
        10          5       8000        10000
        11         10       2000         2000

11 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: How can 5 be both parent and grandparent of 6?

Comment: As per your query, here `ID` 5 is the parent of 6, 8,9 &10 and grandparent of 6 & 11.
So I `TOTAL_AMOUNT` of `ID 5` would be sum of 5 to 11 `ID's` OWN_AMOUNT. That's why it is 200000.
From your query OWN_AMOUNT of 7 & 11 are not in TOTAL_AMOUNT of ID 5.

Comment: Here 5 is parent of 6 & grandparent of 7. It is a typing mistake.

Comment: Have a look at edited query, please.

Comment: Can't tell as I can't see code you wrote. Apparently, you did *something* wrong.

Comment: Sorry, there is a mistake on code. Now its ok with package.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a correlated hierarchical query:

```sql
UPDATE parent_child p
SET total_amount = (SELECT SUM(own_amount)
                    FROM   parent_child s
                    START WITH s.ROWID = p.ROWID
                    CONNECT BY PRIOR id = parent_id);
```

Which, for the sample data, outputs:

| ID | PARENT_ID | OWN_AMOUNT | TOTAL_AMOUNT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | *null* | 100000 | 100000 |
| 2 | *null* | 15000 | 15000 |
| 3 | *null* | 10000 | 12000 |
| 4 | 3 | 2000 | 2000 |
| 5 | *null* | 100000 | 200000 |
| 6 | 5 | 25000 | 40000 |
| 7 | 6 | 15000 | 15000 |
| 8 | 5 | 30000 | 30000 |
| 9 | 5 | 20000 | 20000 |
| 10 | 5 | 8000 | 10000 |
| 11 | 10 | 2000 | 2000 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/QNnzPv-W)

Comment: @SadmanZIhan I don't know as I cannot see your code. You have a syntax error somewhere and need to debug it.

Comment: Sorry, there is a mistake on code. Now its ok with package.